# Skype video not working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, skype

Hi I have installed Skype in Ubuntu 12.04 and I am able to check video option in Options / Video devices.I am able to test video.But while making calls it could not display the Video of me.Please help me on this.

Even I have tried

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

to open Skype from terminal

Comment: by default the skype in linux doesn't show your own video (i faced), you have to click on `Show video` button on the video window. These controls are located at bottom where microphone,text chat button is.